# VBA Word searching for a line and replacing part of it

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I have to program something quickly for my colleagues, and I've been stuck for a while on the following. The goal is to use data from MS Excel to fill in a MS Word template. It is this latest I have issues with.
The MS Word template is as follow:
[image]

The idea would be to search on the left column (so for example Organism), take that line and replace the right (Click here to enter text) with the corresponding value from MS Excel. But I'm new in VBA and I'm unsure how to correctly program this. The code I have for the moment is this one, which finds the correct left string, and replaces that with the string + MS Excel value, but not replacing in the right column.

```
Sub SearchAndReplace(inputKey As String, inputVar As String)
With Selection.Find
  .Text = inputKey
  .Replacement.Text = inputVar
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne, Forward:=True, _
  Wrap:=wdFindStop
End With    
End Sub
```

Help would be very much appreciated. If something is not clear please feel free to ask.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you have posted does not make clear whether the items are in a table, but it does show that there are content controls.

If you have set up the content controls correctly with titles and/or tags then you can use something like this:

```
Sub AddTextToContentControl(targetDoc As Document, ccTitle As String, textToAdd As String)
  Dim ctrl As ContentControl
  Set ctrl = targetDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle(ccTitle).Item(1)
  ctrl.Range.Text = textToAdd
End Sub

Sub AddTextToContentControlByTag(targetDoc As Document, ccTag As String, textToAdd As String)
  Dim ctrl As ContentControl
  Set ctrl = targetDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag).Item(1)
  ctrl.Range.Text = textToAdd
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm unsure if the Word document uses content control, it was made before my time. I will check this later. I do know it's a table, each line is a cell, and the left column is separated from the right with a tab.

Comment: @Tomekke - the content controls are plainly visible in your screenshot.

Comment: Oh ok, those were content controls. Well, once I configured them correctly your solution worked! Thank you very much for you help!